# How to pass a parameter to a modal in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm making a small blog writing project in Angular for practice. I will show all article card on screen with delete button. When the user press on delete button a modal should open asking for confirmation. Here's the code:

**articles.component.html**

```
<!-- CARD -->
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3" *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index;">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{article.title}}</h5>
                <a (click)="showDialog()" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                {{article.date}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- MODAL -->
<p-dialog header="Deleting this article!" [(visible)]="display" [modal]="true" [responsive]="true" ...>
    <span>Are you sure?</span>
    <p-footer>
        <button ... (click)="display=false; onPress(article.articleid)" label="Yes">Yes, Sure</button>
        <button ... (click)="display=false" label="No">No, leave it!</button>
    </p-footer>
</p-dialog>
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

And here is my logic:
**article.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...    
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {
  
  articles = []; // contains title, date, articleid

  constructor(..., private _articleService: ArticleService) { }

  display: boolean = false;

  showDialog() {
      this.display = true;
  }   
 
  ngOnInit() {
    // logic to populate this.articles[] array 
  }

  onPress(id) {        
    this._articleService.deleteArticle(id)
    .subscribe (
      data => {
        console.log("deleted");
      }
    );
  }
}
```

But on pressing **Yes, sure** button I'm getting this error:

> ERROR TypeError: _co.article is undefined

I know the reason. Actually `(click)="display=false; onPress(article.articleid)"` in modal have no idea about `article.articleid`.

How to pass `articleid` there. Please help me. Is my entire logic wrong?

Comment: Thank you everyone who took time and efforts to help me. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set a variable to store the clicked post's id. so while clicking delete assign the Id to that variable and on confirmation use this is to delete the post

article.component.html

```
<!-- CARD -->
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3" *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index;">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{article.title}}</h5>
                <a (click)="showDialog(article.Id)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                {{article.date}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- MODAL -->
<p-dialog header="Deleting this article!" [(visible)]="display" [modal]="true" [responsive]="true" ...>
    <span>Are you sure?</span>
    <p-footer>
        <button ... (click)="display=false; onPress(true)" label="Yes">Yes, Sure</button>
        <button ... (click)="display=false" onPress(false) label="No">No, leave it!</button>
    </p-footer>
</p-dialog>
```

article.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...    
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {
  
  articles = []; // contains title, date, articleid

  constructor(..., private _articleService: ArticleService) { }

  display: boolean = false;
  deletePostId:number;
  showDialog(id) {
      this.display = true;
      this.deletePostId=id
  }   
 
  ngOnInit() {
    // logic to populate this.articles[] array 
  }

  onPress(isDelete) { 
    if(isDelete && deletePostId)  {
    this._articleService.deleteArticle(this.deletePostId)
    .subscribe (
      data => {
        console.log("deleted");
      }
    );
 }else{
  this.deletePostId = null;
 }     

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to simply store the `article` object that triggers the modal.

In this case, re-using the `display` variable:

1. Change the type to `any`
2. Assign the clicked the entity to `display`

```
<a (click)="showDialog(article)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>
```

```
display: any = undefined;
showDialog(selected: any) {
    this.display = selected;
}
```

3. Then you can use the `display` variable properties in your click listener.

```
<!-- MODAL -->
<p-dialog header="Deleting this article!" [(visible)]="display" [modal]="true" [responsive]="true" ...>
    <span>Are you sure?</span>
    <p-footer>
        <button ... (click)="display=undefined; onPress(display.articleid)" label="Yes">Yes, Sure</button>
        <button ... (click)="display=undefined" label="No">No, leave it!</button>
    </p-footer>
</p-dialog>
```

Answer (score 2):

define a varible named `articleId` in your component :

```
articleId:number;
```

then pass your `articleId`  to showDialog method
HTML:

```
   <a (click)="showDialog(article)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>
```

Typescript:

```
 showDialog({articleid}) {
      this.display = true;
      this.articleId=articleid; // new 
  }
```

now , in yur **onPress** method you have to use `articleId` like the following :

```
  onPress() {        
    this._articleService.deleteArticle(this.articleId)
    .subscribe (
      data => {
        console.log("deleted");
        this.articleId=undefined;
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `article` from your `Modal` represented by `*ngFor= "let article of articles"` was out of scope so Ive moved it in the correct `div`. Ive added a `*ngIf="article` on the button just to make sure but you dont necessarily need it.

```html
<!-- CARD -->
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3" *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index;">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{article.title}}</h5>
                <a (click)="showDialog()" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                {{article.date}}
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- MODAL -->
        <p-dialog header="Deleting this article!" [(visible)]="display" [modal]="true" [responsive]="true" ...>
            <span>Are you sure?</span>
            <p-footer>
                <button ... *ngIf="article" (click)="display=false; onPress(article.articleid)" label="Yes">Yes, Sure</button>
                <button ... (click)="display=false" label="No">No, leave it!</button>
            </p-footer>
        </p-dialog>
    </div>
</div>
```